# Arch Linux dhcpd won't start on boot - cannot find subnet declaration

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I want to have a DHCP server running on Arch Linux, but I'm having problems. I'm having an issue with getting dhcpd to start on boot. It will start ok when I manually run `sudo systemctl start dhcpd@eth0.service` when I've logged in.

I'm running the latest version of Arch Linux (4.7.0-1) and I've followed the Arch networking wiki to get this set up.

**My setup**

- dhcpcd is disabled
- I have used systemd-networkd to do the static ip (it is enabled), the config is (`/etc/systemd/network/wired.network`):

  ```
  [Match]
  Name=eth0

  [Network]
  Address=10.0.0.2/24
  Gateway=10.0.0.1
  ```

  - My `/etc/dhcpd.conf` is simple:

    ```
    option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.2;   
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;   
    option routers 10.0.0.0.1;   
    subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.0.0.5 10.0.0.50;   
    }
    ```
- I created my systemd service file (`/etc/systemd/system/dhcpd4@.service`) and enabled it with `systemctl enable dhcpd4@eth0.service`:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=IPv4 DHCP server on %I
  Wants=network.target
  After=network-pre.target
  Before=network.target

  [Service]
  Type=forking
  PIDFile=/run/dhcpd4.pid
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpd -4 -q -pf /run/dhcpd4.pid %I
  KillSignal=SIGINT

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

When I reboot I get an error in the start up that says (when i run `journalctl -xe`):

```
 No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
 ** Ignoring requests on eth0....
```

Then when I run `systemctl start dhcpd4@eth0.service` it all runs fine no problems.

I've done a lot of googling but found no solution to this issue. I've tried tweaking the files (`dhcpd.conf`, `dhcpd4@.service` and `wired.network`) to hard code interfaces, add extra DHCP declarations, alter Unit wants etc and more; but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem!
The problem is that the boot process is trying to start DHCP service whilst the network is starting up/being configured, and so DHCP can't find an working interface to bind to. This is why it always worked when I ran the start dhcpd service manually and didn't work on boot.

I found a clue to the answer from this post: [dhcp on arch linux - rasp-pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/22412). The user used a restart declaration in the unit file, which made the service retry every 6 seconds until the service was up. - This temporary solution worked for me too.

I had a dig around the systemd web site on the [special targets](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#network-online.target) page and found this link to [running services after the network is up](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/). From this page's recommendations I made the following adjustments:

- In the dhcpd4@.service unit file I removed the `Before=...`, changed `After` to `After=network-online.target` and changed `Wants` to `Wants=network-online.target`
- I also enabled the `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`to start on boot.

It now works on boot! However, the recommendations page does say that enabling `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` does slow down your boot time and can do by 90 seconds (if I've read it correctly). Though I've only noticed about 1 or 2 seconds increase in boot time in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to restrict dhcpd to only eth0? If not, you may simply use the standard systemd service file `dhcpd4.service`.

If you are, maybe try changing

```
After=network-pre.target
Before=network.target
```

to

```
After=network.target
```

This is also specified in the [standard dhcpd4.service](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/dhcpd4.service?h=packages/dhcp).
It seems that dhcpd needs an active interface - which is not guaranteed if it is started *before* `network.target`.

Comment: I'm not explicitly trying to restrict it to just eth0, I only have one NIC so don't need to worry about it. As you suggested I can just have it as ...dhcpd4.service.

With the After and Before, I did try changing these without any change in behaviour.

I have managed to find the answer to this problem, which I've put below.